# Convert 3 columns (day,month,year) to PHP Date/Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 3 columns, all VARCHAR(20)

```
dob_day
dob_month
dob_year
```

how can i convert these into a PHP Date/Timestamp and get the age of a person (the row)

for example, if i had the following:

```
dob_day = 07
dob_month = 08
dob_year = 1994
```

this needs to display 19 as the user will be 19 years of age

Comment: _“I have a database with 3 columns, all VARCHAR(20)”_ – why, oh why …? Anyway, RTFriendlyM: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: as a side help, why do you have a varchar(20) for columns that will only ever hold data of 2, 2 and 4 chars? Also, using mysql DATE column type to hold it all might be useful here (1 column instead of three) and then use PHP to work with the full date. but depends on your setup etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be storing the date of birth as a `date`. This solution will return the age from the database side:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day),CURDATE()) AS `age`
```

**Result**

```
| AGE |
-------
|  19 |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f771/1)

Comment: PS - `CONCAT(dob_year, '-', dob_month, '-', dob_day)` is all that's needed to convert to a MySQL date.

Comment: @ebyrob I don't quite understand your comment. Isn't that what I'm doing?

Comment: Absolutely, my point was just that you have answered two questions with 1 line of code...  1) Convert to date, 2) Retrieve age.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dob_day = '07';
$dob_month = '08';
$dob_year = '1994';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));


$diff = $now->diff(new DateTime($dob_month.'-'.$dob_day.'-'.$dob_year));

printf('%d years, %d month, %d days', $diff->y, $diff->m, $diff->d);
```

Prints: `19 years, 1 month, 26 days`

If you just need to print the year, something like this might work:

```
$dob_year = 1994;
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$now = new DateTime(Date('Y-m-d'));
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", Date("Y-m-d"));
$year = $date->format("Y");
echo $year - $dob_year;
```

Prints: `19`